# determining whether multiple checkboxes are checked or not

Tags: jquery

I have 4 checkboxes on a page (#Cbox1...#Cbox4) and I'm trying to use multiple if statements to determine which combination of the 4 are checked and then do 'something' based on that.  For example, I'm trying to use the following to see if the 1st, 3rd and 4th are checked:

```
if ($(("#Cbox1").is(":checked"))&&(("#Cbox2").is(":not(:checked)"))&&(("#Cbox3").is(":checked"))&&(("#Cbox4").is(":checked"))) {
            //do this
}
```

Whenever the 'if statements' are run I'm getting an error.  Can anyone offer advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break your code down:

```
if (
    $(
        ("#Cbox1").is(":checked")
    )
    &&
    ...
) {
```

You can see that you're attempting to run `("#Cbox1").is(":checked")` and then run the jQuery constructor `$()` on that. Obviously that first operation doesn't work.

This will work:

```
if (
    $("#Cbox1").is(":checked") &&
    $("#Cbox2").is(":not(:checked)") &&
    $("#Cbox3").is(":checked") &&
    $("#Cbox4").is(":checked")
) {
```

If nothing else, this should be a lesson in the importance of formatting your code legibly.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is incorrect.

It should be like this:

```
if ( $("#Cbox1").is(":checked") && 
     $("#Cbox2").is(":not(:checked)") && 
     $("#Cbox3").is(":checked") && 
     $("#Cbox4").is(":checked") ) {
            //do this
}
```